# train the CNN model with 2D Matrix and the scaler value

Tags: conv-neural-network, regression, prediction

I would like to make some doubts clear. I have labelled dataset which is number of 2D matrix as the input and one scaler value as an output. I am thinking to apply the Convolutional Neural Network Architecture, make the regression model for prediction.

My question is, can it be possible to train the CNN model with 2D Matrix and the scaler value?

My expected output is also a Scaler valueö

Comment: Without having an understanding of your data its tough to say for certain. But at face value yes, this may be possible. If your data has spatial patterns (across rows and columns of the matrix; i.e. image type data) useful for predicting the scalar then a CNN should be appropriate. If it does not (neighboring cells do not have any meaningful connection to each other) then a dense/MLP may be more appropriate. Also, if possible try to normalize the scalar to `[0,1]`.

Comment: I have lebelled dataset. I want to train the CNN with this labelled dataset. So it is possible to train CNN with my Input data (2D matrix) and Output data (scaler value) for training the CNN..right?

Comment: Again, without more information about the data set its tough to say for certain. And again, if your data (the 2D matrix) has spatial patterns then a CNN makes sense to use. So with the information you've provided my best answer to you is "sure try it". // If by labelled data set you mean that the scalars are actually class labels (a mapping between a class and a single unique value) then you should one-hot encode the labels prior to training.